How to be GDPR compliant by loading plugins?
As far as I understand I need a cookie consent before loading for example a Google Analytics plugin. Loading only a script file depending on user choice would be ok, because it is simple javascript, but if we are talking about an entire plugin, how to block it based on user choice. Do I need a plugin wrapper/loader sort of or is this solvable at all without explicit support of the actual plugin? I ask this, because my site needs to be GDPR compliant...

I don’t see why you’d need to disable a whole plugin. You shouldn’t be setting cookies from PHP - it doesn’t work well with caching - so you should only need to control script loading. And I’d be surprised if plugins that set cookies didn’t have a solution for this built in nowadays.

@Rup Well if you have a soluion, then go on and write about it! :-)

Which plugin are you talking about, a specific Google Analytics plugin? And how are you setting / storing cookie consent - with an existing plugin, or with your own cookie and DOM events etc.?

@Rup It is a general solution, because I don't know the future and there are countless marketing, analytics, etc. plugins. E.g. this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ga-google-analytics/ As of the storage, I set a cookie with javascript, which I read with a must-use plugin, which turns off the GA plugin when there is no consent. From caching perspective it is an interesting problem, but it is a working solution. For example this can solve the caching problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58621049/forcing-browser-to-consider-cookie-value-in-cacheing-response or make it even worse, lol.

@Rup Looks like there is not really good solutions just proposals for cookie fragment based caching: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/understanding-vary-header/ I am not certain how others solve it. I mean certainly if a script loads the other scripts, then it is possible to cache it, but you need to have some sort of standard solution for this or a built-in solution in Wordpress. I don't know such a solution. Do you?

@Rup As of storing the consent this is interesting: https://www.cookieserve.com/knowledge-base/cookie-consent-and-compliance/where-to-store-cookie-consent/ Some people store it in the database as an evidence. I am not entirely sure this is necessary if the data protection authority checks the company.

I found that I need a must-use plugin.
First I created a folder: wp-content/mu-plugins. Next I added the following code:
error_log('plugin filtering');
add_filter('option_active_plugins', function (array $plugins){
    error_log(json_encode($plugins));
    return $plugins;
});

It lists all my plugins before they are loaded.
So I can use a cookie to store user consent for different plugins and use this filter to turn off the plugins which don't have user consent simply by unset($plugins[$noConsentPlugin]);.
The only drawback that this solution requires a page reload after giving consent, while if we are not talking about plugins, but Javascript files, then a simple Javascript file loader would suffice without reloading the page. So it depends on how deeply for example Google Analytics is added to the page. As far as I know it can be as simple as loading a Javascript file or adding a pixel, which can be done with this latter solution.
Either way it takes around a day to implement a proper cookie consent plugin, so it is not that hard.

To make your site GDPR compliant when loading plugins like Google Analytics, you're correct that you need to get user consent before loading any cookies or scripts that track personal data. Here's how to approach it:
1. Cookie Consent Banner
Implement a cookie consent banner that allows users to choose whether or not to accept different categories of cookies, such as analytics cookies (used by Google Analytics).
Make sure the banner is set to block cookies and scripts (including plugins) until consent is obtained from the user.
2. Blocking Plugin Scripts Until Consent
For plugins like Google Analytics, you cannot simply load the entire plugin before the user gives consent because that would immediately set cookies, violating GDPR rules.
Solution 1: JavaScript-Based Conditional Loading
You can use JavaScript to conditionally load the plugin based on user consent.
For example:
If the user gives consent for analytics, your script dynamically loads the Google Analytics plugin using document.createElement('script').
If they don’t give consent, the script won’t load, and the plugin will remain inactive.
Example Code:
if (userConsentForAnalytics)
{
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
}
Using a Plugin Loader or Wrapper
If your website uses multiple plugins that need conditional loading based on user consent, you can consider building or using a plugin loader.
A plugin loader is a wrapper script that only initiates a plugin based on the user’s consent choices. For instance, it checks consent first and then proceeds with loading the plugin if allowed.
This method centralizes control and makes it easier to manage multiple plugins.
4. Plugin-Specific Solutions
Some plugins come with built-in support for GDPR compliance, offering settings to delay activation or disable certain tracking features until consent is given. Check if your plugin has such settings, as it simplifies the process.
If no support exists, the above script-based conditional loading will be the way to ensure compliance.
5. Use Consent Management Platforms (CMPs)
A CMP can help manage user consent for cookies and plugins by automating the process. CMPs can ensure that no cookies or scripts are loaded until appropriate consent is given and help categorize cookies into different types (necessary, marketing, analytics, etc.).

It's more complicated than that though. You'll need to cope with activating the scripts after the cookies are accepted on the same page load, which is what the OP's solution is missing.
